# Extending a PrimeNg component inside Angular2

Tags: angular, primeng

Due to some use cases, I need to extend a PrimeNG component in Angular2. For proofing purpouses, I chose using the `DataTable` since it is complicated enough.

After literally copy pasting the `@Component` annotation, I have added:

`export class PPDataTable extends DataTable {}`

At this point I  get the following error: `No provider for DataTable`. If I add `DataTable` to the `providers` array in the annotation, the content of my `DataTable` is empty.

Therefore I tried adding: `{ provide: DataTable, useValue: PPDataTable }` which yields in some errors such as : `TypeError: co.dt.isSorted is not a function`. I tried logging `this.isSorted` in the new class and it does exist.

How do I extend something like this?

Also, got any better solutions to change the selector name of a PrimeNg component ( wrap it somehow ) ?

***Edit***

After looking some more through the debug stack I found this:[image]

It seems that instead of providing directly the object, I am providing an array containing the object and this is (by my guess) the cause of the error. If I go in the sourcecode and change it to `dt[0].isSorted()` it works!

How do I provide the object directly?

***Answer***

Seems that if I provide `{ provide: DataTable, useExisting: PPDataTable }` it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out my good friend:

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { PrimeNgClassToExtend } from 'path';

const DATATABLE_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyClassThatIsExtending),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
    selector: 'my-class-extending',
    providers: [DATATABLE_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
    template: ``
})
export class MyClassThatIsExtending extends PrimeNgClassToExtend {
}
```

We use [NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR](https://angular.io/api/forms/NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) in order to connect your custom control to ngModel with Control Value Accessor.

Check [this tutorial](http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel) also, could help.

Comment: I'm still getting the same TypeError as explained in the question.

Comment: Feels as if I'm providing the `ExtendingClass` correctly but for some reason the components that use a `@Inject(forwardRef(() => DataTable)) public dt:DataTable` can't access functions on `dt`. Also, doesn't work even if I manually overwrite the method on the extending function, still sais it is undefined.

Comment: @user1640736 Try `constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => DataTable)) dt) {}`.