# PrimeNG p-orderList disable multiple selection of items

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG's p-orderList. By default, the metaKeySelection attribute is true which implies that a metaKey(ctrl key) is needed to be pressed to select multiple items. I was rather looking for a way to completely disable selection of multiple items. I should be able to select ONLY ONE item in the ordered list.
There is no metaKey attribute available for p-orderList. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<p-orderList [value]="policyList" [listStyle]="{'min-height':'calc(100vh - 325px)'}" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
  <ng-template let-policy pTemplate="policy">
    <span>{{policy}}</span>
  </ng-template>
</p-orderList>
```

PS: `onSelectionChange($event)` is triggered every time you select items from the ordered list. `$event.value` contains the array of the items.

Comment: Please correct your tagging! Read what all tags are and see which one you are actually not using

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy flag for it but it can be achieved through calling a function that basically replaces the entire selection array with just the original selected row. 
You will need a variable to store the previous value for comparison.

```
  onSelectionChange(event) {
    if (event.value.length === 1) {
      this.tempValue = event.value[0];
    }
    else {
      event.value = [this.tempValue];
    } 
  }
```

Can also be simplified by passing event.value to the function

```
(onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the `metaKeySelection` input property? (as shown [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/orderlist))

```
<p-orderList [metaKeySelection]="false" [value]="policyList" [listStyle]="{'min-height':'calc(100vh - 325px)'}" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
  <ng-template let-policy pTemplate="policy">
    <span>{{policy}}</span>
  </ng-template>
</p-orderList>
```

Comment: the [metaKeySelection] just enables toggling of one or more elements. If its true (which is by default), you will be able to select one item BUT need ctrl key to select multiple items. If metaKeySelection is false, you can select multiple items by default. I want to avoid that itself.

Comment: Mmm, i don't think you can achieve that, as you can see here: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/orderlist/orderlist.ts#L158 orderlist handle ONLY multiple selection. You could try to extend the orderlist component and create your own one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519015/extending-a-primeng-component-inside-angular2